# How to get metrics of all parallelisms in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In flink web UI, I can get metrics of each parallelism,

for parallelism 0, it likes:

```
0_filter_numberOfRecords in
```

for parallelism 9, it likes:

```
9_filter_numberOfRecords in
```

How to get the same metric of all parallelism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the aggregated metrics by directly querying Flink's rest endpoint. You need the following information:

1. Job id `jobId` identifying the job to which the operator belongs you want to query
2. Vertex id `vertexId` identifying the operator from which you want to retrieve the metrics

The `jobId` can be obtained by querying `http://flink_cluster:port/jobs`.

The `vertexId` can be obtained by querying `http://flink_cluster:port/jobs/:jobId` which gives you the job information (list of operators with their vertex ids).

Having obtained the required ids, you can send a GET request to:

`http://flink_cluster:port/jobs/:jobId/vertices/:vertexId/subtasks/metrics?get=filter.numberOfRecords`

Please replace `:jobId` and `:vertexId` with the respective ids.

If you want to aggregate the metrics over a sub range of sub tasks, then you can change your request to `subtasks/metrics?get=filter.numberOfRecords&subtasks=0-1,4-5` in order to specify the subtasks to include in the aggregation.

Comment: Hi Till,

 I have an operator with two subtasks and I see similar ndividual subtask metrics referenced as <subtask_index> reported using a reporter. Can you please let me know if the above aggregation can be done with a reporter and then I can send it to TS DB?